# Revert Subversion change in TortoiseSVN Repo Browser, NOT local checkout

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

We have a single huge Subversion repository, so we typically only checkout particular areas to work on locally.

We are about to introduce a new automated process that will automatically update svn externals and commit to the repo, via a Jenkins build.

My question is: if these changes are wrong, can we revert them by using TortoiseSVN's repo browser, as opposed to having to check out the repo and revert it using TortoiseSVN's context menu?

Answer (score -1):

No it is not possible. You can access the log and change the log message etc. but there sems to be no command to undo the changes. In contrast the tortoisesvn client on a checked out version of the repository is able to undo a commit with a new one. But that's what you wanted to prevent.